# Finds method only in main void (cannot find symbol, symbol: method tulosta(), location: class Object)

Tags: java

So the problem is that the method "print()" can be used only in main void. When i try to use it in "changeAccount()" it says "cannot find symbol".

```
public class Main {

    public static ArrayList createAccount(ArrayList accountList) {

        Account account1 = new Account();
        accountList.add(account1);
        return accountList;
    }

    public static int changeAccount(ArrayList accountList) {

        accountList.get(0).print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>(0);
        createAccount(tiliTaulukko);
        accountList.get(0).print();
    }
}
```

Now here is where print methos is called from.

```
public class Account {

    public void print(){

    }

}
```

Comment: Where have you define print ? Please create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the complete error message?

Comment: what does the parameter tiliTaulukko stand for? I didn't find it initialized anywhere.

Comment: @azurefrog yeah I read again the question. Missed that part

Comment: We need the error message and... there's not `return` statement on `changeAccount` method btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `changeAccount` method, the argument `accountList` is declared as `ArrayList`, not `ArrayList<Account>`, so the type of `accountList.get(0)` will be `java.lang.Object`, which does not have a `print()` method defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the type returned from `accountList.get(0)` is not the same in your two methods.

In your `main` method, you have defined `accountList` as an `ArrayList<Account>`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    ...
}
```

So when you call `accountList.get(0)`, you get an `Account` back, and can run `print()` on it without an error.

In your `changeAccount` method, you have defined the `accountList` parameter as a *raw* ArrayList:

```
public static int changeAccount(ArrayList accountList) {
    ...
}
```

So when you call `accountList.get(0)`, you get an `Object` back, which has no `print()` method.

Change the type of your parameter to be `ArrayList<Account>`:

```
public static int changeAccount(ArrayList<Account> accountList) {
    //This should now work
    accountList.get(0).print();
    ...
}
```